# C: Search and Replace/Delete

Tags: c, macos, file

Is there a function in C that lets you search for a particular string and delete/replace it? If not, how do I do it myself?

Comment: `strstr()` + `memmove()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be dangerous to do a search and replace - unless you are just replacing single chars with another char (ie change all the 'a' to 'b'). Reason being the replaced value could try and make the char array longer. Better to copy the string and replace as you into a new char array that can hold the result. A good find C function in strstr(). So you can find you string - copy everything before it to another buffer, add your replacement to the buffer - and repeat.

Answer (score 0):

`<string.h>` is full of string processing functions. Look here for reference:

- http://www.edcc.edu/faculty/paul.bladek/c_string_functions.htm
- http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/node19.html